# Network Unreachable on Android Emulator

Tags: android, networking, emulation

1. It's not a DNS issue. I am trying to access a resource by IP.
2. I can access google from the emulator.
3. I can access the host by 10.0.2.2 -- gives me the default IIS page.

The IP address is question is an intranet address (192.168.200.xxx). I have tried multiple different IP addresses on the network all with same error code: ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.

I've tried to access from chrome too to rule out any issue in permissions.

Comment: So you can access that IP in your computers browser but not on your emulators browser, but you can access other sites on the emulator browser?

Comment: What's your emulator's IP address? I'm guessing it's 10. something. Do you have routing setup between the 10. and 192.168. networks?

Comment: @lbenedetto Yes

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman I too think that it's 10.x.y.z based on emulator networking documentation. but how do I verify?
Do I have to set up the routing on the host or on the emulator? or via ADB?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the emulator OS version from Oreo to Marshmallow fixed the issue.